# How can I export a table from SQL Server to a CSV file, but with an additional column?

Tags: sql-server, data-export

I can export simple data from SQL Server to a CSV file without a problem. Here is a special case. Besides exporting required fields from that table, I need to export an additional field, password]. This field is not present in the table on the SQL Server. This field is a result of manipulating the `studentId` field. Ex, if `StudId` is `11111` then its password is `'XDUBS'`.

```
        'assume the connection works 
        cmd1.CommandText = "select studentID from vwTEST"
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        da.Fill(dt)

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            strStudentID = dt.Rows(i).Item(0)
            enc = encrypt(strStudentID)
            updatePW(strStudentID, enc)
        Next
```

I call the encrypt() to convert studentID to pw and call updatePW() to update the table students, but I am not allowed to add [pw] field into the table. That's why I can't do this way even it works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Temporary table (Create table #name ...);
2. Using user defined function (UDF) to calculate the password.

Comment: Thanks i486; sounds good. But can we create a VB.net code instead of creating a function or store procedure in SQL Server? I don't have permissions to access to SQL Server. Also, I already have a VB.Net function to calculate the password and it works!

Comment: @stakx, I modified the question and added codes. Thanks

Comment: @stakx and i486: If UDF is the only way, can you help me with the t-sql codes to calculate the password? My calc password function is from previous VBA for Access and it happens working in VB.Net.

Comment: @stakx, I will ask a question about how to use a UDF to encrypt a column data. I will post it in t-sql tag. If you and i486 know how to do it, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that there is no special permissions to create temporary tables, i.e. you can create such. Using temp tables/UDF is much better than moving SQL data to VB.net side and process it there. Otherwise you lose the chance to use powerful server and client-server advantages. Try to learn SQL instead of replacing this with client side VB programming - it will be helpful for you.

Comment: PS: Give the algorithm for password calculation if it is not very complex.